# MariaDB default my.cnf in sources

Tags: mariadb

Does MariaDB have a default my.cnf in their sources that contains all params and their default values? I found only [`debian/additions/my.cnf`](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/debian/additions/my.cnf) but it does not reflect all params and seems to be updated occasionally.

For example, PHP has default [`php.ini`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-development) in their sources, so when they change a default value or add a new option they update this file. While upgrading PHP I compare hash sums of original configs and see if something has been changed. I wonder whether MariaDB has a similar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MariaDB does not have a configuration file which would list all available options and their default values. Different MariaDB packages might provide some configuration files, but those are different, they only contain a small subset of options, and the values are different from default ones.

MariaDB default configuration can be obtained by running

```
mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help
```

or, on a running 10.1+ server, by executing

```
SELECT variable_name, default_value FROM information_schema.system_variables ORDER BY variable_name
```

but naturally, neither of these would help to find out that variable values have changed by a hash sum. Luckily, default values of *core* server variables change very rarely in stable releases.